# Camera image quality issue using u crop library

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-development

I am using ucrop library for cropping the image,
but after clicking the image and sending to the urop, quality getting reduced.I tried by using extradata,but the ucrop didn't worked with that

Here is the code

```
    private fun openCamera() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        resultCaptureFromCamera.launch(intent)

    }
    private val resultCaptureFromCamera =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val bitmap = result.data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
                bitmap.let {
                    imageAbsolutePath = ImageUtils.INSTANCE?.saveImage(it, requireActivity()) ?: ""
                    val imageUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        requireActivity(),
                        Constants.AUTHORITY,
                        File(imageAbsolutePath)
                    )
                    val outputUri = File(
                        requireContext().filesDir,
                        "croppedImage${Date().time}" + ".png"
                    ).toUri()
                    val listUri = listOf(imageUri, outputUri)

                    cropImage.launch(listUri)

                } 
            } else {
                dialog?.dismiss()
            }

        }
    private val cropImage = registerForActivityResult(uCropContact) { uri ->
        if (uri != null) {
            listener?.onLaunchCLickListener(uri)
        }
        dialog?.dismiss()

    }
```

Comment: Accoridng to the uCrop documentation you are able to set the compression format, set it to PNG to make it lossless, furthermore it seems you can set `.withMaxResultSize` which will also impact the end results resolution so make sure to set that to it's max size.

Comment: val uCrop = UCrop.of(inputUri, outputUri)
                .withAspectRatio1f, 1f)
                .withMaxResultSize(1920, 1920) it is set

Comment: val imageUri:Uri?
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture")
        values.put(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
            "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis()
        )
        imageUri = requireContext().contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)   data is returning null on the registerForActivityResult